# Jquery .load function is not working as expected

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("button").click(function()
                {
                    $("#div1").load("http://w3schools.com/jquery/demo_test.txt");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1">
            <h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2>
        </div>
        <button>Get External Content</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

The preceding code is an example from W3Schools which I tried to run in my browser. While it works on W3schools window it refuses when I try to run it from my html page.

Comment: *"PS Please only constructive answers"* this is Stackoverflow, only constructive answer are posted...

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools. Ever. http://w3fools.com

Comment: [Learn to debug javascript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners)

Comment: This is what I meant constructive answers only ...

Comment: @NickPapamanolioudakis My comment was constructive. If you knew how to debug javascript, you would have found the error _XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://w3schools.com/jquery/demo_test.txt. Origin http://whatever is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin._ and at least been able to search for what that meant.

Answer (score 3):

Nope! You cannot use JavaScript to load a page from a remote website. This violates [Same Domain Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules).

Comment: Is there any other way that this can be achieved ?

Comment: By uglier means, yes. For example, the `div` element can contain an `iframe` that fills 100% of the div's space, and the iframe points to a remote page.

You can't easily interact with the iframe's contents though...

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/02/09/beginners-guide-jquery-based-json-api-clients/